# Instruments Leaks - Not showing source code for iPhone device

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-leaks, instruments

When I double click one record in **Call Tree**, I can locate the source code. But just for Simulator, shows **Unavailable** for iPhone device testing.

Is this function just for Simulator? Or need some extra settings for 
iPhone device testing?

Simulator:

[image]

iPhone Device:

[image]

I can only click top left infos to show this window, and find the code by myself. And **Source Location** info is too long to show, I need **Copy Selected Frames** and paste it to a text editor to see the full source location info.

[image]

Xcode Version 8.3.2 (8E2002)

iPhone Device iOS version 10.3.2(14F89)